# How do I programatically create an exchange 2010 mailbox using C# without powershell

Tags: c#, active-directory

I'm trying to create a Mailbox within C#, and I cannot use powershell (as per the requirements). 
I have been able to successfully create a Distribution List without the need for powershell functionality.
Looking on various forums, the only possible solutions are not what I have the capabilities of doing.
I wish it were simple enough to utilize this functionality, however, I am in a bit of a jam.

I've managed to add several properties for Exchange 2010 in a mailbox so far, but there are only so many properties I am able to determine.
(msExchUserAccessControl for example).

I'm not sure what information I can provide that would be helpful beyond this. 
Any assistance would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean that you wish to create the mailbox from a client PC, not the Exchange server, and you may not install the management tools on the client, then you may be able to remotly execute the powershell scriptels.  Look here:
[Creating an Exchange 2010 Mailbox from a remote C# program](http://blog.pedroliska.com/2011/07/28/creating-an-exchange-2010-mailbox-from-a-remote-c-program/)